# How to keep in sync git repository and related htdocs directory?

Tags: version-control

I use the following set up for my `@dev` site:

**(a) ../git/repository/dev**

where I keep version control using git,

and a separate

**(b) ../htdocs/dev**

that I have an *almost* exact copy of  *git repositor* (a) used by the http server

How to make sure *git repository* (a) is always in sync with *http* (b) ?

I don't want to version control (b) directly from various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the "post-update" hook in the /hooks directory provided in your .git directory to push a copy (sans -gitignore- the files not needed) each time you make git commits to your dev files